# Put github-script output on new line

Tags: javascript, github-actions, github-script

I have a GitHub Actions pipeline that uses `github-script` to publish comments on my PRs e.g.:

```
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            const output = `line one \n line two'
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: output
            })
```

I want the output to be published on two separate lines but nothing works. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Does double backslashes work? => `line one \\n line two` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use markdown syntax in the body:

```js
const output = `
line 1

line2

### heading

_foo_
`
github.rest.issues.createComment({
  issue_number: context.issue.number,
  owner: context.repo.owner,
  repo: context.repo.repo,
  body: output
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Not having any indentation is important here, otherwise it'll generate a code-block for the whole output